# Why does a chain of ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry calls lose type information when the chain is split into parts?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This works in Spring Boot:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure (final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
            .csrf    ()
            .disable ()
            .authorizeRequests ()
            .antMatchers ("/public/**") .permitAll ()
            ...
```

This doesn't:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure (final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry registry = http
                .csrf    ()
                .disable ()
                .authorizeRequests ();

        registry.antMatchers ("/public/**") .permitAll ();
```

The compilation error is

```
cannot find symbol
    symbol:   method permitAll()
    location: class java.lang.Object
```

When the chain of builder calls is split like this, `antMatchers` returns `Object` instead of `ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry`? Why?

Practical question: How do I store the builder object when a chain is half-built and continue it with subsequent calls?

Theory question: Why can't the compiler see the type?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The complete theory is answered here (see below for your specific case):

- [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Your compiler or IDE should've given you a warning. Essentially, [`ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry.html) is an inner class and its enclosing class, [`ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.html), is generic. An inner class type is always tied to its enclosing type (and its parameterization).

Because you've declared your `ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry` variable without qualifying it with its enclosing type (and without a type argument), it's considered to be of the raw `ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry` type, and all generics are erased (ie. `antMatchers` has a return type of `Object` rather than whatever `C` *should've been* bound to) as explained in that canonical post about raw types I linked above.

Qualify your type appropriately with its parameterized enclosing type

```
ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry registry = http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests();
```